# LEGO set restore-er? (Emerald Night)

Tags: trains

I just dug up my old LEGO Emerald Night from when I was 10 or so. As I lifted it from the box it was in pieces, with the only parts intact being the piston mech, tender, and passenger car. I got it back to its former glory but it's still missing a few internal and external parts. If there was someone out there who could tear it down and look for the missing components that would be awesome!

Answer (score 5):

This is fairly easy to do yourself. You can get a listing of all the parts that you should have for the set via a reference site such as Bricklink. Here's the Bricklink inventory for that set:

http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=10194-1

You can then purchase any missing pieces. The best place to do this is probably on Bricklink as well.

You can then rebuild this set from the instructions. If you've lost the instructions, they are available directly on LEGO.com as a PDF. [Brickset](http://brickset.com/sets/10194-1/Emerald-Night) also provides easy access to these files. Here are the two instruction booklets on LEGO.com:

- [Part 1](http://cache.lego.com/bigdownloads/buildinginstructions/4611661.pdf)
- [Part 2](http://cache.lego.com/bigdownloads/buildinginstructions/4581168.pdf)